# Overly complex list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of objects with an attribute called mgmt_classes that is itself a list.

```
systems = [System, System, System,...]
System.mgmt_classes = ['foo','bar']
```

I want to identify the System objects within the systems list that have a mgmt_class named 'foo'. I came up with two ways to do that, but I don't like either one.

Ugly list comprehension

```
matching = [system for system in systems 
            if len([mc for mc in system.mgmt_classes 
                    if re.search(search, mc)]) > 0]
```

Ugly nested loops

```
matching = []
for system in systems:
    for mgmt_class in system.mgmt_classes:
        if re.search(search, mgmt_class):
            matching.append(system)
```

I don't like either one of them. Is there a more elegant way of doing this? My gut is telling me that the ugly nested loops would be the better solution of the two since it's easier to follow.

*Edit*:

I want to be able to search for partial terms in mgmt_classes, so 'foo' would get me 'food' or 'football' for example.

Comment: So you want the systems with `'foo'` in `mgmt_classes`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
matching = [system for system in systems if 'foo' in system.mgmt_classes]
```

The `if` statement checks if `'foo'` is in the attribute `mgmt_classes` - much simpler than using regular expressions.

However if your condition requires using regular expressions, use this:

```
matching = [system for system in systems if any(re.search('foo', i) for i in system.mgmt_classes)]
```

This is simply a oneliner version of Kirk's answer.

Comment: Well, what if I did want to use a regular expression to look for a mgmt_class that started with 'foo', matching 'food' or 'football'?

Comment: @DandyPandy That's when you'd use something like the `hasmatches` function I described.

Answer (score 4):

If your matching criteria is sophisticated, consider factoring it out into another function like:

```
systems = [System, System, System,...]
System.mgmt_classes = ['foo','bar']

def hasmatches(classes):
    return any(re.search(search, mc) for mc in classes)

matching = [system for system in systems
    if hasmatches(system.mgmt_classes)]
```

`hasmatches` returns True the first time it finds a match in the list of classes, or else False if none of them match. Then the list comprehension calls it on each system and collects the ones where `hasmatches` evaluates to True.

If it's really as simple as looking for a specific value, lose the regular expressions in favor of direct string comparisons:

```
matching = [system for system in systems if 'foo' in system.mgmt_classes]
```

Comment: I moved to the coast and I are smart now.